# Iterate over a list and apply modulus/remainder to each element

Tags: list, erlang, modulo, erlang-otp

A method that returns a new list formed by applying the second argument as a modulus operand on each list member, with two arguments: a list and a numerical value.

My current method only applies modulus operand to the first element and not all the elements.

I'm trying to use the cons operator to build the new list.

```
modList([Head | Tail], Num) -> [Head rem Num | Tail].
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.
You're writing a recursive function, so what you need next are two things:

1. The **recursive step**: At some point in the body of your function, you need to apply your same function to the rest of the list (i.e. `modList(Tail)`).
2. The **base case**: If you apply the recursive step repeatedly, since you're removing one element from the list on each iteration, at some point, you'll have a list that doesn't match your function head pattern (`[Head | Tail]`). That will lead to a `function_clause` error that you can fix by… of course… adding a clause for that list. Since that clause will likely not need to be recursive (i.e. it will return a hardcoded value), that will close the recursion loop and your recursive function will be complete.

Extra tip: It's generally more idiomatic to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for function names, module names, and atoms in general in Erlang. In other words, a more *common* name for your function would be `mod_list/2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
> Num = 5.
5
> [X rem Y || X <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], Y <- [Num]].
[1,2,3,4,0,1,2]
```